# enzyme shallow's contains test comes negative even thought the expected text are generated

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, enzyme

This is my test code

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import ApplicationStatus
  from 'models/ApplicationStatus';
import ApplicationStatusLabel
  from 'component/ApplicationStatus';

describe('<ApplicationStatusLabel />', () => {
  it(`should render a label if a user have submitted an
      application`, () => {
    const status = new ApplicationStatus({ status: 'pending' });
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <ApplicationStatusLabel
        planApplicationStatus={status}
      />
    );
    console.log(wrapper.text())
    expect(wrapper.contains('received your application')).to.equal(true);
  });
```

and there is my label react code

```
const PlanApplicationReceivedStatus = () => (
  <div className={styles['plan-trial']}>
    <div className={styles['plan-trial-headline']}>
      {"We've received your application."}
    </div>
    <div className={styles['plan-trial-text']}>
      {
        `We'll get back to you via email within 24 hours.
        `
      }
    </div>
  </div>
);


const ApplicationStatusLabel = (
  {  planApplicationStatus }
) => {


  if (
    planApplicationStatus &&
    planApplicationStatus.status === 'pending'
  ) {
    return PlanApplicationReceivedStatus();
  }

  return null;
};
```

However the test always reports failure

```
 AssertionError: expected false to equal true
      + expected - actual

      -false
      +true

      at Assertion.assertEqual (node_modules/chai/lib/chai/core/assertions.js:487:12)
      at Assertion.ctx.(anonymous function) [as equal] (node_modules/chai/lib/chai/utils/addMethod.js:41:25)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/components/PlanApplicationStatus.spec.js:19:
```

I have put in a `console.log` statement to print out the content. I can see the output as such:

```
 We've received your application.We'll get back to you via email within 24 hours.
```

So it seems to me the react component works as expected. So why the `contains` test failed?